# subscript out of range in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am working on a script to check on folder share where I will pass the folder location as variable to the script (example: Script.vbs D:\share)but when I run it I got an error "subscript out of range vbscript 800a0009"

Script given below,

```
Const EVENT_TYPE_ERROR   = 1
Const EVENT_TYPE_WARNING = 2
Const EVENT_TYPE_INFORMATION = 4

Set oParameters = WScript.Arguments
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

ShareName = oParameters(6)
clog = "Windows Share"
Source = "ShareSecurity"

Dim WshShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set ObjExec = objShell.exec("icacls """"& ShareName & """"")
Set objStdOut = ObjExec.StdOut

While Not objStdOut.AtEndOfStream
   strLine = objStdOut.ReadLine
   If InStr(strLine,"Everyone") Then
set ObjExec1 = objShell.exec("icacls """"& ShareName & """"")
completeshare = ObjExec1.StdOut.ReadAll()
strCommand = "eventcreate /T Error /ID 422 /L " & Chr(34) & Clog & Chr(34) & " /SO " & source & " /D " & Chr(34) & completeshare & "Network share with Every one access is created and the information is given below" & Chr(34)
WshShell.Run strcommand

   End If
Wend

wscript.quit
```

Comment: Why `oParameters(6)`?

Comment: Was just going to ask the same ^^

Comment: @Nikki9696 Because they pass the share name into the script as argument number 7 perhaps? Still 7 is a lot so questioning it is understandable.

Comment: He specifically gave the example in his post where there were no other arguments. If there are no other arguments, then (6) would be out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Const EVENT_TYPE_ERROR   = 1
Const EVENT_TYPE_WARNING = 2
Const EVENT_TYPE_INFORMATION = 4

Dim WshShell, ShareName

Set oParameters = WScript.Arguments
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

ShareName = oParameters(6)
clog = "Application"
Source = "EventCreate"

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set ObjExec = objShell.exec("icacls """& ShareName &"""")
Set objStdOut = ObjExec.StdOut

While Not objStdOut.AtEndOfStream
   strLine = objStdOut.ReadLine
   If InStr(strLine,"Everyone") Then

set ObjExec1 = objShell.exec("icacls """& ShareName &"""")
completeshare = ObjExec1.StdOut.ReadAll()
strCommand = "eventcreate /T Error /ID 425 /L " & Chr(34) & Clog & Chr(34) & " /SO " & source & " /D " & Chr(34) & "Network share with Every one access is created and the information is given below " & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & completeshare & Chr(34)
'strCommand = "eventcreate /T Error /ID 1999 /L APPLICATION /D" & Chr(34) & "Network share with Every one access is created and the information is given below " & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & completeshare & Chr(34)

WshShell.Run strcommand

   End If
Wend

wscript.quit
```

This one worked when I parsed the variable like below,
script.vbs 1 2 3 4 5 6 D:\share
Worked !!!!
Thanks all for your valuable inputs.

Comment: I have modified the script.from ShareName = oParameters(0) to ShareName = oParameters(6)

Answer (score 4):

Read and follow docs: [Arguments Property (WScript Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b05k8s(v=vs.84).aspx):

> The `Arguments` property contains the [`WshArguments` object (a
>   collection of arguments)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ss1ysb2a(v=vs.84).aspx). Use a **zero-based index** to retrieve
>   individual arguments from this collection.

Hence, in case of **expected** `Script.vbs D:\share` (or `Script.vbs "D:\share"`), use next code snippet:

```
Set oParameters = WScript.Arguments
If oParameters.Count > 0 Then
   ShareName = oParameters(0)
Else
   '   usage prompt and then `Wscript.Quit`, or
   ShareName = "some default value"
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
ShareName = oParameters(6)
```

Should be this:

```
ShareName = oParameters(0)
```

Comment: This is more a comment / reply rather then an answer.

Comment: Yes, I should use oParameters(0), I am trying to get the value from an application which passes Parameter 6, now it is working fine.